# Multiple Variant Selectors On The Collection Page - Shopify

Tags: shopify, liquid

I am using a customized Pipeline 4 Theme if thats important.

I have edited my store to have cart button and variant selector on my collection pages.

The result is that I have a radio input(css to look like button), where user can select the prefered variant and below an atc button that is adding the selected variant to the cart. ( That is working well ).

The problem is, because all variant types ( color, etc. ) are in that one radio input, its very long (like in the screenshot).

[image]

Full screenshot of my collection page right now: https://snipboard.io/eQhOjV.jpg

So I would like to separate the different variant types ( color, material etc. ) but keep the buttons layout, because we are avoiding using dropdown list. But when I tried to separate variant selectors it gets complicated with the add to cart button, how I can update the selected variant.

Below are my code:

```
    <!-- form -->
         <form action="/cart/add" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="product-form-{{ product.id }}" class="product-form">
                      
                    {% if product.variants.size == 1 %}
                        <input type="hidden" id="variant-select" name="id" value="{{ product.variants.first.id }}" />
                    {% else %}
          
                    
                  {%- for variant in product.variants -%}         
                    <input 
                      type="radio" 
                      name="id" 
                      class="variant-option"
                      value="{{ variant.id }}" 
                      id="variant-option-{{ variant.id }}" 
                      {% unless variant.available %} disabled{% endunless %}
                      {% if product.selected_variant.id == variant.id %} checked{% endif %}
                    >
                    <label for="variant-option-{{ variant.id }}">{{ variant.title }}</label>
           <img class="hided" src="{{variant.image.src | img_url: 'large'}}"
                        alt="{{variant.title}}"/>
                    {%- endfor -%}
           
                    

                    
                   
                    {% endif %}

         

                   {% unless sold_out %}
                     <br><br>
                 
                    <div class="add-to-cart__wrapper" style="margin-top:0px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
                      <button type="submit" name="add" class="btn btn--splash btn--full uppercase addToCart">
                        <span id="AddToCartText">Add to Order</span>
                      </button>
                    </div>
                 
                
                     
                  </form>  
                    {% endunless %}
```

I tried to edit the code as below following some tutorials i found:

```
<div class="product-form__input product-form__quantity" {{ block.shopify_attributes }}>
                
          
              {%- unless product.has_only_default_variant -%}
                {%- if block.settings.picker_type != 'button' -%}
                  <variant-radios class="no-js-hidden" data-section="{{ product_card_product.id }}" data-url="{{ product.url }}" data-update-url="false" {{ block.shopify_attributes }}>
                    {%- for option in product.options_with_values -%}
                        <fieldset class="js product-form__input">
                          <legend class="form__label">{{ option.name }}</legend>
                          {%- for value in option.values -%}
                            <input type="radio" id="{{ product_card_product.id }}-{{ option.position }}-{{ forloop.index0 }}"
                                  name="{{ option.name }}"
                                  value="{{ value | escape }}"
                                  form="{{ product_form_id }}"
                                  {% if option.selected_value == value %}checked{% endif %}
                            >
                            <label for="{{ product_card_product.id }}-{{ option.position }}-{{ forloop.index0 }}">
                              {{ value }}
                            </label>
                          {%- endfor -%}
                        </fieldset>
                    {%- endfor -%}
                    <script type="application/json">
                      {{ product.variants | json }}
                    </script>
                  </variant-radios>
                {%- else -%}
                  <variant-selects class="no-js-hidden" data-section="{{ product_card_product.id }}" data-url="{{ product.url }}" data-update-url="false" {{ block.shopify_attributes }}>
                    {%- for option in product.options_with_values -%}
                      <div class="product-form__input product-form__input--dropdown">
                        <label class="form__label" for="Option-{{ product_card_product.id }}-{{ forloop.index0 }}">
                          {{ option.name }}
                        </label>
                        <div class="select">
                          <select id="Option-{{ product_card_product.id }}-{{ forloop.index0 }}"
                            class="select__select"
                            name="options[{{ option.name | escape }}]"
                            form="{{ product_form_id }}"
                          >
                            {%- for value in option.values -%}
                              <option value="{{ value | escape }}" {% if option.selected_value == value %}selected="selected"{% endif %}>
                                {{ value }}
                              </option>
                            {%- endfor -%}
                          </select>
                          {% render 'icon-caret' %}
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    {%- endfor -%}

                    <script type="application/json">
                      {{ product.variants | json }}
                    </script>
                  </variant-selects>
                {%- endif -%}
              {%- endunless -%}

           
            
             

                    {%- form 'product', product, id: product_form_id, class: 'form', novalidate: 'novalidate', data-type: 'add-to-cart-form' -%}
                      <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ product.selected_or_first_available_variant.id }}" disabled>
                         <div class="add-to-cart__wrapper" style="margin-top:0px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
                      <button type="submit" name="add" class="btn btn--splash btn--full uppercase addToCart">
                        <span id="AddToCartText">Add to Order</span>
                      </button>
                    </div>
                        
                     
                    {%- endform -%}
                  </product-form>
                
            
              </div>
```

I do get the visual i wanted in the screenshot
[image]

But the Add to Cart button is not working

Would be great if anyone can help!

Comment: What console errors are you getting? Do you have some javascript in place to select the variant id from the selected options? I'm not familiar with that theme but it would be the same javascript used for the product template as these are custom elements it should be contained in the web component

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't have a clue, I just happen to know some basic HTML/CSS to know where to edit the code so I can follow the tutorial if provided, and I really don't know much about JS

Comment: Can you see it's not normal html, there are custom elements like ```variant-radios``` if this is from your theme and not the tutorial, search your theme for this, you'll find where the web component is being set up, it will be in its own js file or in the theme.js or something like that, from here you will see how this custom element works. If this code is not from your theme then its not going to work as the custom element hasn't been set up. If u aren't learning js then you'll need to follow an exact tutorial for the theme, otherwise someone has to look closely at the code.